# Firebase not sending reset password email

Tags: firebase

I'm using the standard email/password authentication and followed the implementation given here https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html. Console tells me that that no error was returned and password email has been sent successfully but I don't get it. I've checked all the folders.

Are there some security rules that may be preventing this? I have the standard rule

```
auth.provider === 'password' && auth.uid === $userid rule
```

on 'write'.

I know something is up because I can't login anymore, so some kind of temporary password has been set in Firebase.

Comment: Security rules have no impact on password reset emails in Firebase. But are you trying to reset the password that you use to login to Firebase? Or is a user of your app trying to reset their email+password account?

Comment: Its the latter. A user of the application needs to reset their password because they don't remember it anymore.

Answer (score 19):

Turns out it was going into the spam folder. Gmail was marking it as spam for some reason.
Probably need to upgrade my account to send a proper white label email.

Comment: The password reset emails Firebase sends are the same, no matter if you're on a free or paid plan.

Comment: Mine was going to spam too

Answer (score 6):

Your Password reset mail maybe on SPAM folder it happened to me so check your spam folder also and why in spam because of custom domain not connected after connect custom domain its works fine